# ReactJS Read Json from url real time

Tags: reactjs

I am looking into ReactJS. I've created database and added a table with some simple data.
Next I created a php file that will display the data in json format like this:

```
[{"ID":"1","Name":"name","Color":"green"}]
```

Next I've created a reactjs skeleton page and I'm trying to get it to read and display the json data but cannot find a simple example anywhere.

How can I get reactjs to read json from a url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h0ctutpv/1/) which is a simple getting started and will give you an idea how to proceed.

Also, I think you will find [this example from React Docs about loading data from ajax](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html) helpful. Code from there is as follows:

```
var UserGist = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      username: '',
      lastGistUrl: ''
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    $.get(this.props.source, function(result) {
      var lastGist = result[0];
      if (this.isMounted()) {
        this.setState({
          username: lastGist.owner.login,
          lastGistUrl: lastGist.html_url
        });
      }
    }.bind(this));
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.username}'s last gist is
        <a href={this.state.lastGistUrl}>here</a>.
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.render(
  <UserGist source="https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists" />,
  mountNode
);
```

Comment: Great! I'll have a play later...Wish there was some site will snippets like this for React but I guess it's too new yet :)

Comment: So, does react not check itself for changes? And would this be different to just using normal js Ajax ? A bit confused with what react can do

Comment: React allows you to think of your View in terms of Components. This ends up simplifying the code when you are creating more complicated front end interactions. I actually learnt the Flux architecture along with React and would recommend reading up that as well.